# Structure Saved in a Session Variable

Tags: casting, structure, session-state

The ReportInfo is a structure.  The structure works fine on one web page but I am trying to use it on another web-page.  Here is where I saved the ReportInfo structure to the Session Variable

Session["ReportInfo"] = reportInfo;

On the other web-page, I re-created the Structure and then assign the session variable to it, like this...

reportInfo = (ReportInfo)(Session["ReportInfo"]);

I get the following run-time error:

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Specified cast is not valid."
  Source="App_Web_-s8b_dtf"

How do I get the ReportInfo structure out of the Session variable to use again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the value of `Session["ReportInfo"]`? Perhaps it's `null` or some other unsavory value? Also, I assume `reportInfo` in the second page is of type `ReportInfo`?

Comment: The of Session["ReportInfo"] is what it should be on the original page...  But I cannot tell what the value is once on the new page...

Comment: So you have an issue with your session persistence, not the cast itself. Check other session object and/or your IIS settings